# Checking if file exists in a SFTP server with java

Tags: java, file, sftp, exists, jsch

I´m trying to check if a file exists in an SFTP server, currently I'm using JSch library and executing an "ls" command and then working with the output from server.

I don't know if fetching the output from server is the only way to do this, it's there a better way to do this?